# How to setup two block server (Ip based) with two differents ports with Nginx on CentOS?

Tags: nginx, centos, nginx-config

I'm on CentOS 8 my nginx configuration file is in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

I don't have any DNS therefore I would just use the server ip to access the server, I search a way for host *two website* in *one Nginx server* (without DNS)

Thank you for your help :))

Ps. I think the best way is using two differents ports, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your options are

- Use two different ports, for example:

  ```
  server {
      listen 80 default_server; # listening port for site #1
      ... # site #1 configuration
  }
  server {
      listen 81 default_server; # listening port for site #2
      ... # site #2 configuration
  }
  ```

  If you have SELinux enabled system, ports used for this configuration must be labeled as `http_port_t` type, otherwise nginx won't be able to bind on those ports. You can check avaliable `http_port_t` ports with

  ```
  semanage port -l|grep http_port_t
  ```

  command. To label some new port with `http_port_t` type (for example, port 81), use

  ```
  semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 81
  ```

  Do not forget to open used ports for external access via your firewall.
- Serve the second site under some URI prefix, for example, use `http://<ip>/` for the first site and `http://<ip>/blog/` for the second one:

  ```
  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      location / {
          # configuration for site #1
          root /path/to/site1;
          ...
      }
      location /blog/ {
          # configuration for site #2
          alias /path/to/site2/;
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

  Using this configuration could be tricky because every link on your site #2 must be either relative or start with `/blog/` prefix, otherwise that link won't be served with `location /blog/ { ... }` block therefore leading to site #1.